# MSBuild finding a tool path

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to set up an MSBuild target to run `npm install` as part of the build process.

```
<Target Name="EnsureNpmBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
   <PropertyGroup>
       <NpmToolExe Condition="$(NpmToolExe) == '')">npm</NpmToolExe>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Exec Command="$(NpmToolExe) install" />
</Target>
```

If the user has installed Node.js themselves, I would like to use that version. Assuming it's installed its location into the %PATH% environment variable on Windows, the above target will work.

The part I'm having trouble with is trying to use a fallback to the npm tool which is bundled with Visual Studio (for those in my team who aren't doing JS development, but still have the project as part of their solution). This version can be founder under `$(VsInstallDir)Web/External`.

Although I can build an `ItemGroup` of the possible locations of the `npm.cmd` file, I don't know how to take that as an ordered list and use the first version which exists.

Any suggestions on how I can make MSBuild search a few locations to find the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a target I created to find different executables; it should be easy to adapt for your requirement.

```
  <Target Name="FindBestSqlServerToolsDir">

    <!-- This target populates the property SqlServerToolsDir, which should be used when executing SQLCMD.EXE and BCP.EXE. -->

    <ItemGroup>
      <Temp_SqlServerVersions Include="130" />
      <Temp_SqlServerVersions Include="120" />
      <Temp_SqlServerVersions Include="110" />
      <Temp_SqlServerVersions Include="100" />

      <!-- Create an item for each possible path, ordered from most-preferred to least. -->
      <Temp_SqlServerToolsDirs Include="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\%(Temp_SqlServerVersions.Identity)\Tools\Binn\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="About to check the following directories in the order listed for the files BCP.EXE and SQLCMD.EXE. The first one where both are found will be used as the value for $ (SqlServerToolsDir)." />
    <Message Text=" - %(Temp_SqlServerToolsDirs.Identity)" />

     <!-- Create a copy of the list with its order reversed. -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <Temp_SqlServerToolsDirs_Reversed Include="@(Temp_SqlServerToolsDirs->Reverse())" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- Test all paths, from the least-preferred to the most. Whenever a path passes -->
      <!-- the condition, set/overwrite the value of this property. The final value -->
      <!-- of this property will thus be the most-preferred path that passes the condition. -->
      <SqlServerToolsDir
        Condition="Exists('%(Temp_SqlServerToolsDirs_Reversed.Identity)BCP.EXE')
              And Exists('%(Temp_SqlServerToolsDirs_Reversed.Identity)SQLCMD.EXE')">%(Temp_SqlServerToolsDirs_Reversed.Identity)</SqlServerToolsDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Error Condition=" '$(SqlServerToolsDir)' == '' " Text="None of the following directories contained both BCP.EXE and SQLCMD.EXE: @(Temp_SqlServerToolsDirs)" />

    <Message Text="$ (SqlServerToolsDir): $(SqlServerToolsDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Could you explain (maybe add some comments), how this code achieves what you say?

Comment: @PaulTurner - Done. :)

Comment: The reverse-ordered evaluation is the trick I was missing; great stuff.

Comment: Very elegant solution to achieve this!

Comment: @EmielKoning - Thanks! (If you think it's useful, you can upvote it.)